# Mongodb - Express, how to get the "id" properly? It gives an empty [Object, Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am trying to build an application with MERN stack,
here is my Item model:

```
const Item = require("../../models/Item");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  handler:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model("item", ItemSchema);
```

delete function with the mongoose objectId:

```
router.delete("/:id", auth, (req, res) => {
  var id =  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  Item.deleteOne({ _id: id})
    .then(() => {
      console.log(id);
      res.json({ success: true });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).json({ success: false });
    });
});
```

The result of the console.log(id) is:

```
undefined
```

I've tried different versions, for example with the Mongodb ObjectId

```
const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
router.delete("/:id", auth, (req, res) => {
  var id = ObjectID(req.params.id).toString();
  Item.deleteOne({ _id: id})
    .then(() => {
      console.log(id);
```

this console.log(id) gives:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

I console.log(req.params) and the result:

```
params: { id: '[object Object]' }
```

How can I retrieve id properly to delete the item from Mongodb database ? My action file in React is like that:

```
export const deleteItem = itemId => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_ITEMS });
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/items/${itemId}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(itemId)
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: itemId
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Check the argument value you are passing down to `deleteItem` action. I don't believe you are passing down the correct argument. `params: { id: '[object Object]' }` tells me that `itemId` is an JSON object and not an id string.

Comment: You are right I checked it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing the valid mongoose object id.

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
    return res.send("Please provide valid id");
  }
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  console.log(id);
  return res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Here are the curl requests:

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/1 # Please provide valid id 
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/4edd40c86762e0fb12000003 # Hello World!
```